# How can I keep emails from a given domain out of my mailchimp lists?

Tags: magento, mailchimp

A mailchimp list is fed by Magento which also processes eBay and Amazon orders.

I need to keep the lists free of Amazon emails, but this is difficult to do on the feeder end.

What are the automatable options for cleaning a mailchimp list of a particular domain? API, sending blacklist for a domain, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to do this manually or through the API if you don't want those people on the list at all. If you just don't want to SEND to those addresses, you can create a saved segment for email address doesn't contain "@amazon.com" and always send to that segment.

Comment: Cool. Not sure whether its a new feature, but the "Keep Updated" checkbox made this the sub-segment thing workable. Seems this was not an option last time I tried to make this work.